# Kubernetes service discovery doesn't resolve service host on minikube

Tags: dns, kubernetes, service-discovery, minikube, kube-dns

I'm trying to run two services with k8s running on minikube installation.
So I have the sevice `Foo` and `Bar`, so when I'm accessing the service `Foo` it must trigger service `Bar` to get the data.

Here is the deployment configuration for `Foo` service
`foo-deployment.yaml`:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: foo-server
  labels:
    app: foo-server
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: foo-server
        serving: "true"
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: foo-server
        image: foo-container
        env:
        - name: BAR_SERVICE_URL
          value: http://bar-server:8081
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
          name: http
```

`foo-svc.yaml`:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: foo-server
  labels:
    app: foo-server
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - port: 8080
    targetPort: 8080
    name: http
  selector:
    app: foo-server
    serving: "true"
```

The `BAR_SERVICE_URL` evn variable is used inside the `Foo` so the service knows the host to `Bar`.
And here is the service configuration for `Bar` service
`bar-svc.yaml`:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: bar-server
  labels:
    app: bar-server
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - port: 8081
    targetPort: 8081
    name: http
  selector:
    app: bar-server
```

`bar-deployment.yaml`:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: bar-server-v1
  labels:
    app: bar-server
    version: "1.0"
spec:
  replicas: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: bar-server
        version: "1.0"
        serving: "true"
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: bar-server
        image: bar-container
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8081
          name: http
```

When I'm accessing the `Foo` service with the minikube ip and exposed service port I receive the following error in the pod logs:

```
2018-02-08 14:32:25.875 ERROR 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "http://bar-server:8081/endpoint": bar-server; nested exception is java.net.UnknownHostException: bar-server] with root cause

java.net.UnknownHostException: bar-server
```

However, I can access the `bar-server/endpoint` using the minikube ip and exposed port like this `http://192.168.99.100:31168/endpoint`.

So looks like I can access the `Foo` and `Bar` services from outside the cluster. But `Foo` service cannot resolve the `Bar` service host and cannot access it.

**UPD**: Here are some update with troubleshouting details.

- On `minikube` the `kube-dns` addon is enabled.
- Trying from the iside of `Foo` pod to `wget` to the `Bar` service endpoint. I'm able to do it via IP address of the `bar-server` but not with `bar-server:8081/endpoint`.
- Trying `nslookup kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local localhost` looks good. Here is the ouptput:

  Server:    127.0.0.1
  Address 1: 127.0.0.1 localhost
- Also `dns` pod looks up and running. Here is the output for `kubectl get pods -n=kube-system | grep -i dns`

  kube-dns-6777479f6b-vxd7m               3/3       Running   9          1d

Comment: Hi Sergii, were you able to solve this? I have a similar issue on my own Minikube deployment.

Comment: Having same issue with latest Minikube and Core DNS

Comment: @alexvicegrab my case was that I have update the minikube without doing `minikube delete` so it was fixed by deleting the minikube cluster and starting it again

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer!
In my own case there seems to be some issue with how the Peer interacts with services on K8S when using Minikube. Same thing works completely fine when I use a real K8S cluster on the cloud.

Answer (score 4):

Kubernetes does service discovery using DNS (`kube-dns`). If DNS in k8s is working, service `Foo` should be able to `ping` or `curl` service `Bar`, and vice-versa.

A way to check if `kube-dns` is working is to see if the following commands work inside any pod:

```
nslookup kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local localhost
nslookup kubernetes.default localhost
```

`kube-dns` pod's health can be checked in the output of:

```
kubectl get pods -n=kube-system | grep -i dns
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestions how to troubleshoot it. I have updated the question with the results of these commands. `dns`pod is up and running, but the `bar-server` host is not resolved.

Comment: @SergiiBishyr glad to help, upvote my answer if you think it is useful!

Comment: It is useful and helped me to debug the issue. I did upvote it :)

Comment: `nslookup` failed for me but `dig kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local` worked

Answer (score 1):

Try env variable BAR_SERVER_SERVICE_HOST. Do not inject it, kubernetes injects it for services within the same namespace

Read about service discovery options here:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#discovering-services

Comment: Thanks! Is this the right way of doing service discovery with `k8s`?

Comment: Your approach is the one way of doing it. But there is also a DNS approach, which is what I'm trying to achieve. But it looks like DNS lookup doesn't work. The `kube-dns` addon on minikube is `enabled`.